# identifying broadband connectivity issue: Resolving Host

Tags: router, dns, internet, modem, broadband

I am trying to resolve an issue I have with my broadband internet connection. The issue is as follows:

When using my internet connection at home, loading web pages will frequently (but not always) take a very long time. This occurs on all devices and on all websites that I am trying to access using my broadband connection (wired and wireless). On PC, I will see the "Resolving host" message as described here: http://www.webnots.com/correct-chrome-resolving-host-issue/, which implies that this is a DNS issue. After the host is resolved, the page will load at the expected speed. Connection speed tests like speedtest.net will show low ping and high download and upload results. I tried the steps in the link above but unfortunately to no avail, including:

- Test on a wired connection instead of wireless
- Change DNS server address to a public DNS (8.8.8.8 on my PC and console)
- Cleared DNS cache
- Tested on multiple devices (2 PCs, 3 phones, 1 tablet, 1 home console. All have the same issue)

This issue has been ongoing since I first subscribed to the broadband provider a few months back. I already had countless phone calls with the ISPs customer service as well as multiple visits to my home to try to resolve this issue. However, as many of you have probably experienced first hand, the average ISP customer service employee does not posses the knowledge to solve issues like this. They will always go back to standard internet connection tests to "prove" that the connection is working properly, which does not reflect the issue I am experiencing.

I am looking for a way to measure my internet connection that will identify the problem in an irrefutable way. If possible, I would like to measure if the problem is related to the line, my modem or my router.

I want hand over an explanation of the issue (if possible with a solution) to my ISP to force them to resolve the problem or let me cancel my contract. How can this be done? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's unlikely this problem is related to your line or modem - otherwise everything would be slowed down, not only DNS resolution. The interesting part of your problem description is that the problem doesn't go away if you change the DNS provider. First thing I'd do is to use wireshark to capture DNS packets and verify you are *really* using 8.8.8.8, and it's the late response that causes the slowdown. Next thing I'd do is to check the router setup and disable any suspicious looking DNS features like caching.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, installing wireshark now. I will be home in a few hours and will post the results after. I already tried changing settings on the router (including DNS address) but the router I got from my ISP is extremely limited in settings. I cannot change anything DNS related. I assume that the DNS setting on my PC will always overrule the one on the router?

Comment: What brand and model of router is it? Does your ISP allow to replace it with your own router? If yes, does it allow you to re-flash the router? In the case the router implements mandatory DNS redirection and caching even for other DNS servers (unlikely, but possible), no matter what settings you do on your PC, the router will always use the DNS servers defined by your ISP, and if these are slow ... But that's just one possible scenario out of many.